# How to return a int converted to char array back to main for displaying it

Tags: string, return, program-entry-point, display

My doubts are as follows :

1 : how to send 'str' from function 'fun' , So that i can display it in main function.

2 : And is the return type correct in the code ?

2 : the current code is displaying some different output.

```
char * fun(int *arr)
{
    char *str[5];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        char c[sizeof(int)] ;
        sprintf(c,"%d",arr[i]);
        str[i] = malloc(sizeof(c));
        strcpy(str[i],c);

    }
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {2,1,3,4,5},i;
    char *str = fun(arr);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {    
        printf("%c",str[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You created an array of pointer to characters and allocated space for all the addresses that they should point to. On return, the array itself is gone. The allocated memory for the 5 addresses are still intact.

Comment: "On return, the array itself is gone" , can you please explain it's meaning?

Comment: and after passing it to main ,is 'str' accessing the same addresses?

Comment: The `str` variable is an array of pointer to characters. This is gone when the function terminates. The strings that they point to survives because they were `malloc`ed.

Answer (score 0):

> how to send 'str' from function 'fun' , So that i can display it in main function.

This is the way:

```
char* str = malloc( size );
if( str == NULL ) {
    fprintf( stderr,"Failed to malloc\n");
}
/* Do stuff with str, use str[index], 
 * remember to free it in main*/
free(str);
```

> And is the return type correct in the code ?

No, Probably char** is the one you need to return.

> the current code is displaying some different output.

Consider explaining what/why do you want to do ? The way you have written, seems completely messed up way to me. You're passing array of integer but not its length. How is the fun() supposed to know length of array? Another problem is array of pointers in fun().

You can't write a int to a char (See the both size). So I used char array instead.
However, I'm not sure if this is what you want to do (might be a quick and dirty way of doing it):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char** 
fun(int *arr, int size)
{
    char **str = malloc( sizeof(char*)*size );
    if( str == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed malloc\n");
    }
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
        str[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
        if( str == NULL ) {
              fprintf( stderr, "Failed malloc\n");
        }
        sprintf(str[i],"%d",arr[i]);
    }
    return str;
}

int 
main()
{
   int arr[] = {2,1,3,4,5},i;
   char **str = fun(arr, 5);
   for(i=0;i<5;i++) {    
       printf("%s\n",str[i]);
       free(str[i]);
   }
   free(str);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to display the string after passing it to main function.I should've passed the size also,bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I made these changes to your code to get it working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **fun(int *arr)
{
    char **str = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 5);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if ((arr[i] >= 0) && (arr[i] <= 9)) {
            char c[2] ;
            sprintf(c, "%d", arr[i]);
            str[i] = (char *) malloc(strlen(c) + 1);
            strcpy(str[i],c);
        }
    }
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {2, 1, 3, 4, 5}, i;
    char **str = fun(arr);
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%s", str[i]);
        free(str[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
21345
```

I added a check to make sure that `arr[i]` is a single digit number. Also, returning a pointer to a stack variable will result in undefined behavior, so I changed the code to allocate an array of strings. I don't check the return value of the `malloc` calls, which means this program could crash due to a `NULL` pointer reference.

Comment: Thank you sir,i've understood it now.

Answer (score 0):

This solution differs from the others in that it attempts to answer your question based on the intended use.

> how to send 'str' from function 'fun' , So that i can display it in main function.

First, you need to define a function that returns a pointer to array.

```
char (*fun(int arr[]))[]
```

Allocating variable length strings doesn't buy you anything. The longest string you'll need for 64bit unsigned int is 20 digits. All you need is to allocate an array of 5 elements of 2 characters long each. You may adjust the length to suit your need. This sample assumes 1 digit and 1 null character. Note the allocation is done only once. You may choose to use the length of 21 (20 digits and 1 null).

For readability on which values here are related to the number of digits including the terminator, I'll define a macro that you can modify to suit your needs.

```
#define NUM_OF_DIGITS 3
```

You can then use this macro in the whole code.

```
char (*str)[NUM_OF_DIGITS] = malloc(5 * NUM_OF_DIGITS);
```

Finally the receiving variable in `main()` can be declared and assigned the returned array.

```
char (*str)[NUM_OF_DIGITS] = fun(arr);
```

Your complete code should look like this:

**Code**

```
char (*fun(int arr[]))[]
{
    char (*str)[NUM_OF_DIGITS] = malloc(5 * NUM_OF_DIGITS);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        snprintf(str[i],NUM_OF_DIGITS,"%d",arr[i]); //control and limit to single digit + null
    }
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {24,1,33,4,5},i;
    char (*str)[NUM_OF_DIGITS] = fun(arr);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("%s",str[i]);
    }
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
2413345
```

With this method you only need to free the allocated memory once.

Comment: A 64-bit unsigned int can be 20 digits long: 36893488147419103232.

Comment: 1 : Sir,what is the difference between char (*str)[2] and char *str[2]?

Comment: And if I want to pass int arr[] = {24,1,33,4,5},then How to change the size in the snprintf function . snprintf(str[i],3,"%d",arr[i] ) is Not giving proper output

Comment: `char (*str)[2]` declares `str` as pointer to array of 2 characters while `char *str[2]` declare `str` as array of 2 pointers to char. Note that the declaration does not limit the number of records you can have in there. The allocated memory determines the number of records. Like any pointers, care must be taken not to access beyond what was allocated.